# My DAX code to calculate a moving average is not giving the correct result

Tags: average, dax

I'm hoping that someone can help me.  I'm wracking my brain on this and just cannot get my moving average to give me the correct results.  I first created a daily average to group together a series of dates.  I've named this Booking Average and the results that I am getting are correct.  The problem is that now I need another average which looks at Booking Average and gives me another average of the last 4 weeks.  I created a unique number to group the data but when I try to create the new average it gives me the same average again as the Booking Average.  The measure is called CAY average and below is the code I'm using.

```
=if(countrows(VALUES('Range'[Number])) = 1,
CALCULATE(
AVERAGEX(VALUES('Range'[Number]) , 
'Range'[Booking Average])
,'Range'[Number]<= VALUES('Range'[Number])
&& 'Range'[Number] > VALUES ('Range'[Number])-4)
,BLANK())
```

Is there a way to attach the file so someone can look at it?

Thanks

Comment: You can upload your file to google drive or similar service, and then share the link.

Comment: Here is the link to the file.  Any insight as to what I'm doing wrong would be great.  This is the first time I'm using Power Pivot.  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_eD5osEP6PA4bitYG-qmRexggH3Bcbea?usp=sharing